# Json-Mode / Puppet-Mode unset common functions when installed with use-package

Tags: init-file, package, major-mode, package-repositories, use-package

I'm facing a weird issue in my `init.el`. Installing packages such as `json-mode` or `puppet-mode` (from MELPA Stable) with `use-package` unsets common functions like `forward-word` or `backward-kill-word`. The key bindings are unaffected, the function is simply missing (I get `Symbol’s function definition is void: nil`). This behavior does **not** happen with all packages (I have dozens of other packages in my `init.el` which work just fine).

Here is a minimal `init.el`:

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
    (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize)

(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package)
  )

(eval-when-compile (require 'use-package))
(setq use-package-always-ensure t)                                                                                                                                                                       

(use-package json-mode
  :mode ("\\.json"))


(use-package puppet-mode                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  :mode ("\\.pp"))
```

Running Emacs with a complete clean `.emacs.d` (apart from the init file) first installs `use-package` along with `diminish` and `bind-key` and then downloads the two modes `json-mode` and `puppet-mode` and adds them to the load-path (as expected).

However, opening a text file `test.txt` and then running `M-f` or `M-x forward-word` returns the error:
`Symbol’s function definition is void: nil`

I'm running Emacs 25.1.1

**Is this an issue with these packages, or am I doing something wrong?**

**Can anyone reproduce this problem?**

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but one would usually want to end their `:mode` regexps with `\\'`, which means "end of string", e.g. `:mode "\\.json\\'"`.

Comment: @Basil Thanks for the hint, I'll implement it where necessary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand what's going on internally here (if this is a bug or just my faulty syntax). Nevertheless, I was able to workaround the problem.

Apparently, one cannot use parentheses when having only one argument for `:mode` (e.g. `:mode ("\\.pp")`), but has to omit these (i.e. `:mode "\\.pp")`).

Fix:

```
-(use-package puppet-mode
-  :mode ("\\.pp"))
+(use-package puppet-mode
+  :mode "\\.pp")


-(use-package json-mode
-  :mode ("\\.json"))
+(use-package json-mode
+  :mode "\\.json")
```